# Handling false positive of the classifiers and improving performance when trained with medium sized unbalanced dataset with two features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, imbalanced-data

I have the following unbalanced data set with two features (keon i.e. gender and alder i.e. age) that was balanced using under_sampling method which I trained on different classifier to predict the call_ending_reason where 0 is No and 1 is Yes:

[image]

The balanced dataset with both 1 and 0 have same kind of distribution which can be visualized like this:
[image]

However, after performing under_sampling method on the above shown dataset and training both type of dataset in various classifier from sklearn, the balanced dataset is detecting 1s high precision but 0s with very low precision. The opposite happens when I use the main dataset.

Here is the code:

```py
x = filtered_data_limited_features_with_yes_no
y = filtered_data_limited_features_with_yes_no['call_ending_reason']
del x['call_ending_reason']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size = 0.80)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
# rfc = MLPClassifier(verbose=True,hidden_layer_sizes=(100,50,10),learning_rate='constant',learning_rate_init=0.0001, n_iter_no_change=50, max_iter=100)
# rfc = GaussianNB()
rfc=RandomForestClassifier()
param_grid = { 
    'n_estimators': [50,100,200,500],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
    'criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']
}
CV_rfc_all_data = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10)
# rfc = LinearSVC()
CV_rfc_all_data.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, CV_rfc_all_data.predict(X_test)))

from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

ros = RandomUnderSampler( random_state=1)
df_balanced, balanced_labels = ros.fit_resample(x, y)

####TRAINING AND PREDICTING CLASSIFIER BASED ON BALANCED DATASET
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_balanced, balanced_labels, train_size = 0.70)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


# rfc=RandomForestClassifier()
# param_grid = { 
#     'n_estimators': [50,100,200,500],
#     'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
#     'criterion' :['gini', 'entropy']
# }
# CV_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv= 10)
# CV_rfc = MLPClassifier(verbose=True,hidden_layer_sizes=(100,50,10),learning_rate='invscaling',learning_rate_init=0.0003, n_iter_no_change=50, max_iter=100)
CV_rfc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
CV_rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
# CV_rfc.best_params_
```

**Questions:**

Given the visualization:

1. What classifier should be used to train the classifier with more than 65% precision for both predicting 1 and 0
2. Do I need to scale the data given its only 2 features? If so how should I do that properly to scale both training and testing data

Comment: To me this graph is unclear: first it would be be better to show 2 histograms by gender (or even by target) to see the differences better. Second you mention that this is the balanced dataset, but there are clearly a lot more 0s than 1s. Generally resampling should be used very rarely (can cause various problems), and importantly performance should always be calculated on the original distribution.

Comment: Hi @Erwan, for the balanced dataset, I have updated the scatterplot with two individual scatterplot for both 1 and 0, it seems like zeros and ones have same trend. i.e. the age which gives 0 also gives 1. Thats why when rendering the scatterplot it seems like there are lot 0s than 1 or vice versa. The balanced dataset have records with 27659 0s and 27659 1s respectively after under_sampling.

When I train with original dataset it gives 88% precision for 0s but 1% or 2% for 1s

Comment: What is the proportion of the classes in the original data? My guess would be that 0 is close to 80%, maybe even close to 88%. If my guess is correct, this would mean that the classifier has difficulties distinguishing the classes, so it tends to assign the majority class except for the 'easy' cases of 1. It probably can't obtain 65% precision for both classes. Btw usually performance is given for the positive minority class (1), in the form of precision and recall (and optionally f1-score).

Comment: @Erwan, In the original dataset, I have more than 64 features. However as per feature importance,they are very low to even consider to train. What if I train model 1 in just age and gender, then model 2 in 2 or 3 other features etc and consider the most voted prediction result?

Comment: I meant what is the proportion of the classes, is it for example like 90% of the instances have class 0? Feature importance matters but sometimes it's possible that a model performs well with multiple features even if they have low importance, because the combination of their values can help the model.

Comment: @Erwan, around 95% of the instances have class 0. As a result even with two prominent features i.e. age and gender etc can't bring good precision. The model is very bias as the same range of value for age and gender can represent both classes i.e 0 and 1. On the other hand, when I used the top 12 features as per feature importance, it gives even worse result for which I decided to take two features based on people's experience with the activity related to this dataset classification. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just realized that in the balanced version the train/test split is done after the resampling, this is a mistake: the split should always be done first, otherwise you're evaluating the performance on a different problem (an easier one). In general my advice would be this: 1) forget resampling, it almost never works and causes overfitting or errors. 2) try to keep the other features if possible, they might help improve performance a bit and anyway random forests can ignore features so it doesn't cause any problem to have them

Comment: 3) what matters in your performance is precision and also recall, only for class 1. since your dataset is strongly imbalanced and I'm guessing that the features are poor indicators of the target class, it would be normal that you can't obtain high performance. there's probably not much you can do about it, except if you can have additional features which have more influence on the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `class_weight="balanced"` argument the models, it is supported in most of the models that are supported by **scikit-learn** It won't be magic, but in my experience, it usually works better than under or over sampling.

For the metric used in your grid search, I would use the **f1_score** as suggested by @Erwan, it will penalize heavily poor precision and poor recall, and will reward hyper parameters that yield a more **balanced** model.

Comment: Will try to do that and let you know